# 15 boys choose from 15 girls

Tags: probability

Assume a dancing event in class of 15 boys and 15 girls. Every boy chooses one girl uniformly random. What's the probability of there are a girl chosen by 6 boys?

I got that there are two ways: 1 girl or 2 girls are choosen by 6. And the number of possible outcomes is 15^15

Comment: Exactly $5$ or at least $6$?  What have you done so far?

Comment: Why would the boys choose the girls "uniformly random"?

Comment: @ChristianBlatter:  Ummm.... why *not*?

Comment: Exactly 6. I got that there are two ways: 1 girl or 2 girls are choosen by 6. And the number of possible outcomes is 15^15

Comment: Well this is off topic but it might depends on attractiveness

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Exactly 6. I got that there are two ways: 1 girl or 2 girls are choosen by 6. And the number of possible outcomes is 15^15

$15^{15}$ is the count for possible outcomes iff the identities of the boys and girls are distinct.  So it shall matter *which* one or two from the fifteen girls are favoured by *which* six from the fifteen boys. That shall be much more than two ways.

Count ways *one* from *fifteen* girls are selected by exactly *six* from the *fifteen* boys, and the remaining *boys* select among the remaining girls.  Beware that this includes ways that *two* girls may each be selected by *six* boys.  Count that too, and then use the **Principle of Inclusion and Exclusion**.

Comment: thanks for the usefull answer